# How to setup a password for mailcatcher

Tags: mailcatcher

I have the mailcatcher installed on a server and I would like to protect it with a password.
At the moment, I am accessing it directly, and would like to have the auth_basic 'RESTRICTED ACCESS';

Any idea where can I enable this?

Answer (score 0):

does not seem possible in MailCatcher. You may have to consider using a solution on top to protect your MailCatcher instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing might be to just run Nginx in front to proxy it, or possibly some other lightweight web-server.

For nginx, you could have something simple like this:

```
location /email {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888; # path to your mailcatcher
}
```